# Why is a pea related to peacock?

Tags: etymology

Why is a pea related to peacock?
Is it because of feathers? (which are marked with eyespots)?

Comment: It isn't. The first syllable of the bird's name just happens to sound the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Pea” is an obsolete word for peafowl (and is etymologically unrelated to the vegetable). Like the obsolete “po” and the Scottish “pawn” (which are other words for peafowl), it ultimately comes from the Latin word [pāvō/pāvōnem](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pavo#Latin).

You’ll find [cognates in other languages](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pea#Etymology_2), such as German *Pfau*.

According to the OED, both “pea” and “po” had a part in the formation of peacock/peahen.

Comment: I'm not sure this would be accepted on ELL without any sign of attempted research. I've just been reading elsewhere on the (ELU) site that 'questions that should obviously not be accepted should not be answered'.